# APNS with django-ios-notifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to setup APNS for my app for the first time, and had a question on how to set the user associated with a particular device id. I'm reading the following:

https://github.com/stephenmuss/django-ios-notifications

http://highonpython.com/index.php/setting-up-ios-push-notifications-apns-with-pythondjango-through-pyapns/

I was able to do all of the setup and everything, i'm at the point where i'm trying to write the code for the iOS app. My question is, I have the following as per examples in my iOS App:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UIRemoteNotificationType allowedNotifications = UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound|UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:allowedNotifications];
    return YES;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
    NSString * tokenAsString = [[[deviceToken description]
                                 stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]]
                                stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://your_server.com/add_device_token/%@/", tokenAsString]];
    NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate: self];
}
```

This will allow me to inform my server the token for that particular device. However, my app requires the user to login, and after logging in they have a user id, email, password, etc. Is there a way to delay all of this after the user has logged in? Or is this something I have to do at launch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the answer is no. Best thing is to have the appDelegate remember the deviceToken and then send the users registration for that device at a later time (after login, etc.)